# scripting git fetch pull for password less authentication

Tags: python, linux, git, unix

Hello I am calling git fetch --all from a python script (subprocess). However git requires password authentication. Is there a solution to make this password less?

```
Warning: Permanently added 'devgit,172.17.3.18' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password:
```

Comment: You can add you git credentials to the `~/.netrc` file.

Comment: You can use [ssh keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).